# PDO cannot insert records

Tags: php, pdo

Here i'm trying to insert my records into database using this below code. I'm faced a weird problem here. When i insert the datas i'm getting these following error

> Notice: Undefined index: city_state
>
> Notice: Undefined index: country
>
> Query FailedSQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'GuestState' cannot be null

But when i remove these two `$cstate = $_POST['city_state']`, `$ccountry = $_POST['country']` it would insert the remaining datas properly. I'm new to php pdo. I don't know where i made mistake here? why these two things does not store the datas to database?

```
$cstate = $_POST['city_state'];
$ccountry = $_POST['country'];   
try
    {
        $db = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO ebvouchers ( VoucherReference, BookingDate, CheckIndate, CheckOutDate, MealPlanID_Fk, RoomTypeID_Fk, GuestName, TotalAdults, Childrens, Infants, GuestPhone, GuestEmail, GuestFax, GuestAddressLine1, GuestAddressLine2, GuestRegion, GuestCity, GuestState, GuestCountry, GuestCurrency, GuestCurrencyTo, CurrencyAmount, GuestCurrencyValue ) VALUES ( :reference, :refdate, :ccin, :cout, :r_key, :r_key, :gname, :totaladults, :childrens, :infants, :gphone, :gemail, :gfax, :gaddress1, :gaddress2, :gregion, :city, :state, :country, :currency, :currencyto, :amount, :currencyvalue )");
        $db->execute(array(':reference'=>$creference, ':refdate'=>$crefdate, ':ccin'=>$ccin, ':cout'=>$cout, ':r_key'=>$ref_key, ':gname'=>$cgname, ':totaladults'=>$ctotaladults, ':childrens'=>$cchildrens, ':infants'=>$cinfants, ':gphone'=>$cgphone, ':gemail'=>$cgemail, ':gfax'=>$cgfax, ':gaddress1'=>$cgaddress1, ':gaddress2'=>$cgaddress2, ':gregion'=>$cregion, ':city'=>$ccity, ':state'=>$cstate, ':country'=>$ccountry, ':currency'=>$ccurrency, ':currencyto'=>$ccurrencyto, ':amount'=>$camount, ':currencyvalue'=>$ccurrencyvalue ));
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo 'Query Failed'.$e->getMessage();
    }
```

Comment: The problem is, the `$_POST` does not include the two values: `$_POST['city_state']` and `$_POST['country']`

Comment: echo these two value and place die;
echo $cstate = $_POST['city_state'];
echo $ccountry = $_POST['country']; die;
to check whether they have value or not...

Comment: there is one more way you can set default values in database..

Comment: You also have 2x `:r_key, :r_key`

Comment: @Fred-ii- Those two keys for MealPlanID_Fk, RoomTypeID_Fk..

Comment: How can you use two of the same for VALUES?

Comment: $r_key = $conn->lastInsertId(); this is my :r_key. is that any wrong @Fred-ii-

Comment: What I'm saying is that you have duplicate `:r_key` in `VALUES ( :reference, :refdate, :ccin, :cout, :r_key, :r_key, :gname,` which is not good. Each must be unique.

Comment: @Fred-ii-: i set the unique id. but it didn't store the id. it stores the value of 0 in db. **$meal_rkey = $conn->lastInsertId();, $ref_key = $conn->lastInsertId();** & **':m_key'=>$meal_rkey, ':r_key'=>$ref_key,** . it stores the r_key value correctly. but m_key value is always 0. why?

Comment: Because you **don't** have an `:m_key` in your query, that's what I've been telling you. **You have two** `:r_key`, replace one with `:m_key` and it should work.

Comment: oh @Fred-ii- . i already replaced man **:m_key, :r_key,**

Comment: I noticed you have `':m_key'=>$meal_rkey,` there's an `r` in front of `key`. Maybe it's supposed to be `':m_key'=>$meal_key,` ?

Comment: no it should be $meal_rkey.. look at this **$meal_rkey = $conn->lastInsertId();**

Comment: Ok. Well I don't know what else it could be then. If that is associated with an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column, then it shouldn't be included in the query, that's **IF** it's set to that. Other than that, I can't say for sure. Double-check everything, column types, spelling `Key` is not the same as `key`... stuff like that.

Comment: You're welcome. I also noticed you have two `lastInsertId()` for both `$meal_rkey = $conn->lastInsertId();, $ref_key = $conn->lastInsertId();` I believe you can only have the one `lastInsertId()` http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- : So, only i used **:r_key, :r_key** above i mentioned **$ref_key = $conn->lastInsertId();** & **':r_key'=>$ref_key** & **:r_key, :r_key** for MealPlanID_Fk, RoomTypeID_Fk. i want to insert autoid into two columns (MealPlanID_Fk, RoomTypeID_Fk)

Comment: You can't have two autoid, far as I know.

Comment: is there anyother way to insert two autoids into two different columns?

Comment: This, by the way should have been discussed with the person with whom you've accepted an answer from.

Answer (score 1):

```
Notice: Undefined index: city_state

Notice: Undefined index: country
```

This error itself states that **city_state** and **country** are not defined index in POST Parameters

Check your HTML Form and post these paramter to server, then check.